# Why my input stream string dont go in new line when using \n in txt?

Tags: java, android, textview, newline

Why my input stream string dont go in new line when using \n in .txt???

I am triying to read and then post it into TextView but it shows \n insted of going to new line -.- Cloese enough

```
try {
            reader = new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("koce_podatki.txt"),"UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        for(int i=-1;i<position;i++){
        try {
            temp = "" + br.readLine();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}

        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        temp=temp.replaceAll("\n", "\n");
        nov = temp.split("\\|");

        for(int i=0;i<23;i++){
            podatek.add(""+nov[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Are you using Html.fromHTML() in your TextView.setText() ?

Comment: Nope, if it would be better, how???

Comment: Gives as an example of your input file. Are you having literally `\n` in your input, or do you mean it as 'newline character'?

Comment: slika|Aljažev dom v Vratih|1015 m |April\nMaj\nJunij\nJuilij\nAvgust\nSeptember\nOktober |Julijske alpe ...

Comment: what do you have for `MAX LINES` of your TextView??

Comment: nope i dont... anything else??

Comment: and if i use String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");

It writes \r\n
I am decoding with ZTF-8

Comment: `temp=temp.replaceAll("\n", "\n");` this line is misterious...

Comment: without it its similar than before... ;)

Comment: Have you enabled multi line on the text view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    temp=temp.replaceAll("\n", "\n");
```

This does nothing. If you are expecting real new lines in your text files it is pointless to just replace them with other new lines. If you are expecting the string "\n" in your files (why?) you need *four* backslashes in the first parameter: two for the compiler and two more for the regex parser.